# How to get full HTTP request (not response) headers

Tags: perl, http-headers, httprequest, httpresponse, user-agent

I have a simple code like this:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use HTTP::Request;

my $cookies = HTTP::Cookies->new();
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new();
   $browser->agent(' ... ');    
   $browser->cookie_jar($cookies);   
my $request = HTTP::Request->new();     
my $response;                           
my $url;                                
my $referer;                                        

$referer = '';
$url = 'https:// ...'; # url #1
$request->url($url);
$request->method('GET');
$request->header('Referer' => $referer);    
$response = $browser->request($request);    
print $response->request()->uri()     . "\n\n" .
      $response->headers()->as_string . "\n\n" .
      $response->content              . "\n\n";

$referer = $response->request()->uri();
$url = 'https:// ... '; # url #2
$request->url($url);
$request->method('GET');
$request->header('Referer' => $referer);
$response = $browser->request($request);
print $response->request()->uri()     . "\n\n" .
      $response->headers()->as_string . "\n\n" .
      $response->content              . "\n\n";
```

Now, I want to see full HTTP **request headers** as well, not just response headers.

How can I do it? What has to be added to this code?

Comment: Also, a single `LWP::UserAgent::request` call may end up sending several HTTP requests, in the case of redirects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you almost have it in your existing code. You are accessing the request URI with $response->request()->uri(). The ->request() is your HTTP::Request object. I believe that you can use $response->request->headers->as_string to get what you want.

Comment: Note that this doesn't show the headers actually sent, just what LWP passes to Net::HTTP.

Comment: Since all solutions (available at time of this comment) lead to same or similar output, I reward very first answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
print $response->request->as_string
```

Answer (score 1):

This will show you requests as well as responses.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use LWP::ConsoleLogger::Easy qw( debug_ua );

my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new();

debug_ua( $browser );
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't show the headers actually sent, just what LWP passes to Net::HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

`$request->headers->as_string` and `$response->request->headers->as_string` will you get you the headers of the first and last request passed to Net::HTTP by LWP<sup>[1]</sup>, but these aren't quite what Net::HTTP sends. For example, Net::HTTP can add a `Content-Length` header, a `TE` header, and/or a number of others.

Net::HTTP doesn't keep a record of the headers it actually sends. You will need a wire sniffer (e.g. `tcpdump`) or a debugging proxy (e.g. Fiddler) for that. You could also use a debugger or trace statements to view the request prepared in Net::HTTP::Methods's `format_request`. The most convenient, however, might be to wrap Net::HTTP::Methods's `format_request`.

---

1. These are the same unless the initial request was redirected. To get all the requests (and responses), you can use:

   ```
   while ($response) {
      my $request = $response->request;
      ...

      $response = $response->previous;
   }
   ```